# sharpPDF - help with image quality - pdf specification

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm having troubles with the (slightly outdated) .net library called sharpPDF. We are generating a few images from our gis web application and need to reference the images within this library. The only issue seems to be the compression that the library is using (or not using). The images are PNG32.

The outcome is quite heavily compressed when I compare the results with pdf created via iTextSharp (which is unfortunately a no go for us, don't ask me why).

I've noticed, that in the source code, there is something like the following:

//PDF's Images

```
foreach (pdfImageReference image in _images.Values)
    {
     _trailer.addObject(_bufferLength.ToString());
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, image.getText());
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, "stream" + Convert.ToChar(13) + Convert.ToChar(10));
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, image.content);
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, Convert.ToChar(13).ToString());
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, Convert.ToChar(10).ToString());
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, "endstream" + Convert.ToChar(13) + Convert.ToChar(10));
     _bufferLength += writeToBuffer(_myBuffer, "endobj" + Convert.ToChar(13) + Convert.ToChar(10));
                    currentStep++;
    }
```

which in the runtime looks like this

```
> 60517 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype
> /Image /Name /I60517 /Filter
> /DCTDecode /Width 830 /Height 1300
> /BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace
> /DeviceRGB /Length 77076
> >> stream
> -here goes some bytes- endstream endobj
```

can anyone, who has some pdf specification knowledge, help me out to figure out possible issues with the compression here?

thanks heaps...

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a stream that is generated for a particular image that is being compressed with JPEG compression (DCTDecode = Discrete Cosine Transform = JPEG).  I'm surprised that the PDF generator doesn't have options to select the codec for the image and configure it (for JPEG you should at least be able to set the image quality).

If you're compressing a color/grayscale image that you want to be lossless, you should use flate.  If you are compressing a 1-bit image that you want to be lossless, you should be using CCITT.

If you want a lossy compression (more compression + artifacts) you should use JPEG or JPEG2000 on color/gray and JBIG2 on black and white.

From reading your comment, this is what you should do:

if you're content with JPEG, then you want to use the flavor of Image.Save that includes more codec information, like so:

```
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
{    
    int j;
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
    encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    for(j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
    {
        if(encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
            return encoders[j];
    }
    return null;
}

Stream GetImageStream(Image image, int compression)
{
    EncoderParameters eps = new EncoderParameters(1);
    eps.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter( Encoder.Quality, (long)compression);
    ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
    if (codecInfo == null) throw new Exception("No jpeg codec - WTF?"); // use better message
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, codecInfo, eps);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return stream;
}
```

For anything Flate, you will have to collect the image data row by row and use a flate compression ([Ionic's zlib](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/38bcc359-9b76-91b5-6563-624da6c045d8.htm) is good) and hand compress it.  This is non-trivial.

Comment: I've used FlateDecode and the pdf says : insufficient data for an image. any ideas? thanks a lot

Comment: That sounds like you just changed the dictionary settings without altering image.content.  you have to decode and recompress the image data too.

Comment: How do you generate that stream object?  Where does the data come from?  Most likely you need to set the compression mechanism as the point that that stream/the image dictionary is created.

Comment: sorry guys, I've never worked with the images in c#.... this is how the library gets the content...
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();   
    myImage.Save(outStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    _content = new byte[outStream.Length];
    _content = outStream.ToArray();

even if I change it to .png it doesn't work. seems like there must be the trick with that recompressing you guys are talking about... thanks heaps for helping me out with this one.